# What software Elementary uses for WiFi?

Tags: wifi

What software EOS is using for wifi connectivity? Is this a custom themed NetworkManager? Wpa supplicant? something home made? I am asking about both: the beautiful UI app in the system tray and about the underlying daemon/service that does the actual connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the GitHub for the network switchboard plugin https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-network

Here is the indicator (thanks to @jena):
https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-network

You'll need Vala compiler, Switchboard library, Ninja and other things to compile.

Comment: I think the OP meant the [indicator](https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-network). And the backend should be NetworkManager.